# Java - Print numbers saved to text file in past 24 hours

Tags: java, time

I can't provide any sample code so this will be more of a question that you could maybe provide me in the right direction.

Essentially, at the end of a game round I am exporting the score(points) to a text file. My text file appears like

```
1
3
4
1
2
```

Now what I want to do is, get the top 5 scores that were saved to the text  file in the past 24 hours.

My idea is, once i get the scores that were saved from the past 24 hours, i'll add these to a collection and reverse sort them and use a for loop to print the 5 out. But i have no idea how to get the time.

Comment: You could save the timestamp together with the score and work from there.

Comment: To get the time, you can use Java 8's LocalDateTime API. Also, the classic Date and Calendar APIs are okay.

Comment: @QBrute Now i've added my timestamp the format is `1 2017-12-06 14:32:39.989` but the problem is my array list currently is of type integer which cannot read the hyphens. I am using this list for my other ranking list too (Which is just all-time rankings). Do I need to change my arrayList type?

Comment: I think a standard way to do this would be to clear the file every morning so that you never get scores that are more than 24 hours old. If you really want the scores from the last 24 hours, this won’t work, though.

Comment: No, you don’t need to change your array list (though you may want to). Just read the file from the beginning, skipping time stamps that are more than 24 hours old. Once you meet one that is younger than 24 hours, start adding the scores to your `ArrayList`.

Comment: You need to further process the lines that you're reading before adding them to your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you need to change the format of your file. I would want to use either `Instant.toString()` or `LocalDateTime.toString()` for generating the time stamps. So each line would become like

```
5 2017-11-06T14:52:31.434Z
```

In the example, 5 is the score and 2017-11-06T14:52:31.434Z is an `Instant`. Neither the string representation of `Instant` nor of `LocalDateTime` contains any spaces, so split each line from the file at the space, and you have got the score and the time stamp separately. Feed the timestamp back into `Instant.parse()` or `LocalDateTime.parse()`.

Read the file from the beginning, skipping time stamps that are more than 24 hours old. Once you meet one that is younger than 24 hours, start adding the scores to your `ArrayList`.

For determining whether a time stamp is older than 24 hours, compare it to `Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofHours(24))` or `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome")).minusHours(24)` (substitute your desired time zone). Those classes have methods `isBefore` and `isAfter` for comparison.

Use `LocalDateTime` only if you are sure that everything happens within one time zone only. `Instant` is safe across time zones.

Comment: Thank you, where you mention "split each line from the file at the space", do you mean so when my text outputs to the text file it appears as the score on one line then the date on the next?

Comment: Please see my edit. I am using your file format, having modified it. Many other file formats are imaginable.